# Android dev : need to change Local from a "contact" context

Tags: android, local, contacts

I am a Java dev but I am new with android sdk...

I want to make an app that change the keyboard/local/dictionnary/prediction when you send a message to a contact... using SMS or Whatsapp or else....

My aim is to make an app where you can match a language to a specific contact.

If I want to send a message to Ernesto, the locale will automaticly change into the language I defined in my app (here spanish)... and the same for John ( english ) and Francois ( in french)

If no language is defined for a contact... the default system locale is used...

Is there anybody who could help me to start ?

Thx